# Reading jpg file in OpenCV vs C# Bitmap

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, bitmap, jpeg

After many experiments, I found that reading color jpg file in C++ (OpenCV):

`auto temp(cv::imread("xxx.jpg");`

is different from reading the same file using C# bitmap :

`var temp=new bitmap("xxx.jpg");`

the results are diffrent. There is notable diffrence if I applied some algorithm on them both like GoodFeatureToTrack.

The question is:
How can adoapt the way of C# bitmap loading in the OpenCV. So, I got the same result if I load my image directly in the native part or from the C# Wrapper.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

This code is a c++ function that take some struct that contain an image that was loaded in a manged program (c#) and then load the same image in opencv and compare them.. there is a different!

```
    extern "C" _declspec (dllexport) void test_diff(authenticator_reference_structure* referecnces){
    auto image(cv::imread("white.jpg"));

    cv::imshow("opencv", image);
    auto wrpped(referecnces->references->images->image.getMat());

    cv::imshow("C#", wrapped);
    cv::Mat ss;
    cv::absdiff(image, wrapped, ss);

    cv::threshold(ss, ss, 1, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    cv::imshow("Diff", ss);
    cv::waitKey();

}
```

[image: the thresholded diffrences image]

Comment: What type of image? Grayscale? Colour? Have you tried passing different flags to `imread`?

Comment: Color images
"different flags" for what ?

Comment: You can use `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH` for 16 or 32-bit images, or `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE` to convert to grayscale. The default is `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR` which will result in a 3-channel image. Do your images have an alpha channel maybe?

Comment: I do not think that it contains alpha channel...However, I am going to try CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH

Comment: I tried it. it does not return 3-channels.
I  need the result to be 3 Channels (color)

Comment: It's strange that you see such differences - there should be nothing significant unless one is doing an implicit grayscale conversion or somethng, which doesn't seem to be what you're seeing. Are you sure the problem is the *loading* of the image and not somewhere later? Can you show a minimal code example that has the problem?

Comment: In the worst case: What about writing a wrapper load the image in opencv use it from C# where you would create a bitmap with it, or load the image in C# using the bitmap and then access its data from C++ to create an OpenCV Mat. This way you will use the same loading library in both parts and the results should be the same. I imagine that your final goal is to compare the performance of some code both in C++ or C# so the image loading mechanism is not an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use `getImage()` instead of `getMat()`?

A similar question is being addressed here (using openCV in C# not C++)
http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=188

Comment: You mean to include the EMGU in my c# application and use its image loader? it is possibe solution but I do not want to add EMGU to my c# application just for this purpose..

Comment: Opencv is included in the native part however it is not on the managed part

Comment: You can just install emgu separately, include the header and link against it. You had (presumably) not included OpenCV in your project either? See http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page#Architecture_Overview -- for many things you call it instead of OpenCV (see http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorial)

Comment: sorry, was still editing. but then C## will also be on the native part (it's Windows specific) so that should not change the managed depencies either?

Comment: My c# part does not have any thibg to fo with image processing. It just load an.image and pass it to the native c++  library

Comment: My point is that the raw matrix `wrapped` are the values read by OpenCV (or emgu which is OpenCV for C#). The reason that the image shown on the screen has different values is probably available from the extra info that `getMat()` doesn't provide but `getImage()` does. So if you use the output of `getImage()`, either from OpenCV or emgu then your `wrapper` is probably the same as `image`? If you show us the images `opencv`, `C#` and `Diff` that may help.

Comment: Sorry but GetMat() is a method that I have wrote... it just about converting byte code into MAT nothing happeing there... about the diffrence I am going to edit the question

Comment: Ah. OpenCV also has a `getMat()` function I assumed it was that. Leads me to think that either your getMat has a bug (no code so cannot comment) or the difference that you see comes from JPEG compression. I would not be surprised if those strips were multiples of 8x8 squares (hallmark JPEG feature)

Comment: Yes it seems like that cause I have just tried PNGs and every thing was correct and there is no differences at all

Comment: Problem solved? You can test by making a jpeg from the PNG with the quality setting at 100%. I think that still does the DCT but does not discard any coefficients. Other than that jpeg decoding produces artifacts like those in your `Diff`picture.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: you might wanna read some of this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.photo.digital/yAxoW9HyHPQ/discussion

Answer (score 3):

As others pointed out, if you want to read the image in OpenCV unmodified, set the flags to -1 in the [C++ function](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56), as in:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("xxx.jpg", -1);
```

or use the defined [enum](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80) value:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("xxx.jpg", cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
```

Also note that JPEG images are not guaranteed to be decoded bit-exactly the same by different decoders! It is preferable to use a lossless format like PNG instead (see [#4148](http://code.opencv.org/issues/4148), [#4046](http://code.opencv.org/issues/4046), ...).

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: see my note about lossy JPEG decoding

Comment: yes I did.. but changing the whole encoding is not an option or even I am not authorized to that in my current project

Comment: what I meant is that when you want to compare your different implementations of the algorithm, use PNG images in the tests (which are lossless, think of them like ZIP files)

Comment: I see, it seems that the no easy solution .. I have to change the encoding or adding a library to the manged part.. thanks anyway:)

Comment: @HumamHelfawi umm, both OpenCV `imread` (which uses `libpng` among others) and C# `System.Drawing.Bitmap` (which wraps GDI+) support decoding PNG out of the box... I don't see how it would be difficult to just switch input images from JPG to PNG!

Comment: I have library of millions jpg images that is distributed over the world it is hard to change them all!  Oh! just a minute are you meaning some run-time conversation while reading it ????

Comment: If I understood this right, you have developed your algorithm in C# (some sort of feature detection) and you wanted to compare it to a C++ implementation. What I'm saying is that you should use PNG instead of JPEG images **for the comparison only**, to rule it out as a possibility in case you're seeing differences between the two implementations. Obviously there's no point in converting your 1M set of images, these are already stored and compressed in a lossy format, I'm just talking about the testing phase.

Comment: mmmm not exactly.. I developed my algorithm in native c++ and I want to use it on various platforms (iOS,Andriod and windows...). about windows part, the front-end is a c# application that I have to load the image using it. so it is not a testing problem

Comment: ok I see. So let me get this right, you've now narrowed it down to having difference between 1) loading an image directly using `cv::imread` 2) loading an image in managed C#, passing the pointer to the raw data to native C++, which wraps it inside a `cv::Mat` header. Is that right? Can you test if that happens for both JPEG and PNG images? If that's the case, I would next look for bugs in the marshalling part of your code (your `getMat` method).. Also pay attention to the data types of the images involved (are your images 8-bit vs 16-bit,  do you perform any grayscale to RGB conversion, ..)

Comment: PNGs are 100% the same

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: aha, that's what I've initially suspected :) Different libraries will decode JPEG image slightly differently.. Nothing you can do about it. If you want bit-exactness, you have to consider other codecs. Besides if your algorithm you've developed give widely different results when you feed it images with these kind of differences, then IMO it's a problem.. You should loosen up the parameters a bit (like smoothing the input images, or using a slightly bigger window sizes when doing image filtering, that sort of things...)