# How to solve problem with wrong color of the image in OpenCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, opencv

I have image (**JPG/JPEG**) which looks like this:

[image]

As part of the tests, I decided to create an identical image while preserving the dimensions of the original image through the `.resize` method of the **OpenCV** library. After the transformations, the image changes its original color.

```
image = numpy.asarray(bytearray(response.read()), dtype="uint8")

image = cv2.imdecode(image_file, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

image_height, image_width = image.shape[:2]

dimension = (image_width, image_height)

resized_image = cv2.resize(image, dimension, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

[image]

In a similar [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52495126/4332480), I found that `OpenCV` uses `BGR`. So I converted `BGR` to `RGB` with the code below. Unfortunately it returns me strange result.

```
image = numpy.asarray(bytearray(response.read()), dtype="uint8")

image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

...
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you lost a color profile

Comment: the first image has ProPhoto RGB color profile, while the second image has no embedded color profile. I'm doing some googling on how to deal with color profiles on opencv

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44562776/color-gets-dull-opencv-cv2-imread-cv2-imwrite and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168615/how-to-read-jpeg-image-with-adobe-rgb-colorspace-in-opencv

Comment: OpenCV does not have any support for icc color profiles. you must use another library like PIL

Comment: @Aaron thank you for your response. I was convinced that `OpenCV` has everything you need to work with images. That's why I chose it to work with pictures. Where did you get this information that `OpenCV` does not have any support for `ICC` color profiles?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek one of the linked questions or another one I found with similar search terms

Comment: Also just looking through the docs, there's no mention of icc color profiles (even though there is [color correction](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/de/df4/group__color__correction.html))