# Why ImageMagick changes image brightness when I simply want to convert between JPG and PNG?

Tags: imagemagick

I wanted to batch-convert some JPG images to PNG, so I used the following ImageMagick command:

```
convert before.jpg after.png
```

However, things didn't go as smooth as I planned. See two images below - first is `before.jpg`, second is `after.png`:

[image]
[image]

You can see that the second one is quite darker than the original.

I'm using ImageMagick 6.9.9-19.

Opening JPEG image in GIMP and exporting it as PNG gives expected result - output image is identical to original.

What am I doing wrong?

*Edit:* re-saving `after.png` with GIMP also makes the image identical to original.

*Edit:* even after I saved `after.png` with GIMP, re-converting with ImageMagick breaks colors again (`convert after-gimp.png after-gimp-and-im.png`).

*Edit:* converting to sRGB or CMYK TIFF, or even again to JPG, does not give this problem. However, I still need PNG.

Comment: Check the colorspace in both images. This maybe related to sRGB and Adobe RGB color formats. See this link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33142786/opencv-imrite-gives-washed-out-result-for-jpeg-images

Comment: @Zindarod - no, both images are in sRGB (as reported by `identify -verbose`).

Answer (score 0):

The two images you posted are identical according to IM 6.9.9.20 Q16 Mac OSX `compare -metric rmse GBooF.jpg geDxn.png null:` Which produces: 0 (0). It is possible your viewers may display jpg and png differently, since neither have an sRGB profile. Though, png is usually assumed to be sRGB.

Also my viewer shows both of your images as the same --- no difference, in your post on Mac Safari and using Mac Preview.

Try adding an sRGB profile to your jpg. Then convert.

```
convert GBooF.jpg -profile path2/sRGB.icc GBooF2.jpg
convert GBooF2.jpg GBooF2.png
```

See if those view the same.

Comment: But, as the SO mentions in the comments, the `identify -verbose` command displays `sRGB` colorspace for both images.

Comment: `@Zindarod` ImageMagick assumes sRGB unless the image format supports storing gamma=1 for linear. JPG does not support storing gamma. In his case, both of his files are identical in pixel values (according to compare) and display identically on my Safari and Mac Preview. So the only possible difference would be how any particular viewer decides to display when there is no sRGB profile. Putting the same profile in both jpg and png should make them display on most devices the same because they now have an explicit profile to us (and the pixel data is identical).

Comment: If @Rogach thinks the images are really different and perhaps have been changed by uploading here, then he should zip the files and put a link to the zipped file, so others can examine the original images.