# Open CV cv.imread modifying image

Tags: python, opencv

I use `cv.imread` to read a png file in python. When I then use `cv.imwrite` function to immediately save the image i then find that the colours in the image have changed slightly. I am trying to perform character recognition on this image and the OCR performs far less well on the image in python than the original image.
The first image is the original, and the second is the saved one with OpenCV.

[image: First]

[image: second]

We can see that the green has changed slightly and whilst this does not seem important it affects the OCR and I therefore imagine that other changes are happening to the png. Does anyone know why this might be and how i can resolve this.

The code is as follows

```
img = cv2.imread('file.png')
cv2.imwrite('out.png', img)
```

When I run file.png in tesseract for character recognition I get great results but when I run out.png in tesseract far less words get recognised correctly.

Comment: Are you saving the image as PNG or JPEG? Also take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33142786/2286337).

Comment: Im loading and saving it as a png

Comment: Added code to question

Comment: OpenCV uses BGR format instead of RGB, that's why you observe that diference in color

Comment: @m33n that is only for internal use, when saving it doesn't matter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV imrite gives washed-out result for jpeg images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33142786/opencv-imrite-gives-washed-out-result-for-jpeg-images)

Comment: Could be something to do with png color profiles

Comment: On photoshop when I change the colour profile of the second image to Adobe 1998 RGB the colour of the image changes to the lighter green seen in the first image. However once i save this and run it through OCR I still dont get good results. This shows that there are more underlying changes occurring

Answer (score 4):

When you have a `.png` image file you ought to **read** as a `.png` file.

I downloaded your image and did some analysis myself.

- First, I read the image as you did:

  ```
  img = cv2.imread('file.png')
  ```

  `img.shape` returns `(446, 864, 3)` i.e an image with 3 channels.
- Next I read the same image using `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`:

  ```
  img = cv2.imread('file.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
  ```

  `img.shape` returns `(446, 864, 4)` i.e an image with **4** channels.

`.png` files have an additional *transparency* channel. So next you come accross a `.png` file read it using `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` flag

**UPDATE:**

Enlisting the various ways to read an image:

```
for var in dir(cv2):
    if var.startswith('IMREAD'):
        print(var)
```

returns:

```
IMREAD_ANYCOLOR
IMREAD_ANYDEPTH
IMREAD_COLOR
IMREAD_GRAYSCALE
IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL
IMREAD_UNCHANGED
```

Comment: Great effort...I really did not know that